# Exclude entries with "0" when using AVG

Tags: mysql

I have a number mysql database field named "numbers" in which there are 10 entries with numbers ranging from 0-10.

I would like to find the average of this, but excluding all the entries where number = 0.
But I would also like to count how many entries there are - including the ones where number = 0.

So I can't just add a WHERE numbers!=0, as that'd give a wrong result in my COUNT.

So I need somthing like.

```
AVG(if(numbers!=0)) AS average
```

Comment: you will need 2 selects for it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about this?

```
select avg(nullif(field, 0)) from table;
```

Notice how this method doesn't force you to use a `where` clause, in case you want to use this as part of a larger query where you don't want to exclude zero values in general.

Also, by the way, `avg` skips `null` values, so in the above example we used `nullif` to turn `0` values into `null` values. If you use `null` values to represent values that shouldn't be taken into account for the average (for example, if `0` is a legitimate value), then just use `avg(field)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT avg(case  
              when numbers = 0 then null
              else numbers
           end) as average, 
       count(*)
FROM your_table
```

As NULL values are not used for avg() this should do it.